# PHP Trying to capture nested tags in an array from a string

Tags: php, parsing

Objective: 
Loop through string of characters and store custom objects in an array preserving the nested nature.

Examples below of string and array structure.

I have tried recursive regex but couldn't find a solution as it wasn't really made for this (from what I have researched).

*This is similar to a html/xml parser but for custom tags.*

```
//Array structure
$object["number"];
$object["children"];

    for($i = 0; $<$stringTotal; $i++ {
    $char = $string[$i];

    if ($char == "[") {
    //start new object
    }

    if ($char == "]") {
    //finish current object
    }
    }

Example: 
String = "[1]
[2
  [2.a]
  [2.b
    [2.c]
  ]
]"
```

Comment: I think `explode()` would be of help. Can you add some more detail as to what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I updated the question hopefully it made it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need some recursiveness...

```
foreach($something as $key => $value) {
    $something = do_with_something($value);
}

function do_with_something($recvalue)
{
    if (is_array($recvalue))
    {
        foreach($recvalue as $key => $value) 
        {
            $recvalue[$key] = do_with_something($value);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /* do whatever you want to do and pass it back */
        $recvalue =  $whater_you_want_to_pass_back";
    }
    return $recvalue;   
}
```